# Add Linphone SIP Account iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, linphone

I'm trying to create an App that can comunicate over SIP on local network or over proxy. There is no problem if I add proxy settings to call to proxy device, or if I turn the proxy off to call local device. But I'm unable to call local devices with proxy connected (registered). Linphone is trying to call local address with his proxy account. 
So my question is. Is there any way to add another account for proxy?

In Nadoir version is this really simple using this code:

```
AccountBuilder accountBuilder = new AccountBuilder(mLc);
    accountBuilder.setUsername(username);
    accountBuilder.setDisplayName(displayName);
    accountBuilder.setPassword(password);
    accountBuilder.setDomain(domain);
    accountBuilder.setTransport(transport);

    accountBuilder.setExpires(keepalive);
    accountBuilder.setProxy(proxy);
    accountBuilder.setUserId(authName);
    accountBuilder.setOutboundProxyEnabled(outboundProxy);

    accountBuilder.setEnabled(true);
```

But I haven't found anything like this in iOS version. Is there any way to do that?

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to add more than one account?

Comment: If I understand correctly, I need two accounts. One for local communication and one for SIP proxy. In case I'm right, then yes. I need more than one account :)

Comment: What's meant by Local communication? are you referring to local sip calling? Your one configured account will REGISTER itself on SIP proxy (server) and that single account can communicate/call locally (WLan).